# not able to call Javascript Function from button onclick

Tags: javascript

I have following JS Code. When test.php is loaded and I click on button show function is not getting called.I am trying this on FF. Any suggestions what is wrong here.

test.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/test1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/test2.js"></script>
```

test1.js

```
function show()
{
    alert("hello");
}
```

test2.js

```
      function showHTML()
        {
        var html = "<!DOCTYPE html>";
        html += "<html><body>";
        html += "<input type='button' name='button'  style='width:100px;height:50px;' onclick='show();' />";
        html += "</body></html>";
        document.write(html);
        }

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
      alert("eevnet");
      showHTML();
    }, false);
```

Comment: `document.write`, when called after the initial rendering of the document is finished, __replaces__ the current document. New document == your script file(s) are not embedded any more. Please don't use stuff like `document.write` any more, and look into _Unobtrusive JavaScript_ instead.

Comment: can u please tell me what is Unobtrusive JavaScript

Comment: @CBroe — But it isn't being called after initial rendering in the question.

Comment: It can tell you what Google is if you like ...

Comment: @Alien01 — http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript (sigh)

Comment: @Quentin: Right, but since he is writing a whole document including doctype, html, body etc. the effect should be the same.

Comment: open firebug. First check "is test1.js loaded ?". Second, in firebug console type show() for checking is show function available

Comment: @CBroe — No, it should just generate an invalid document, not overwrite the existing document.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem — http://dorward.me.uk/tmp/js/ (tested in Chrome) — whatever the problem is, it isn't caused by anything you have put in the question. Voting to close as *not a real question*.

Comment: Thanks guys.. my actual issue was I am calling function from load and its not working from load event listener..

Comment: @Alien01 Then don't use `document.write`. Never use it after document load as it rewrites the whole document.You can for example do what I suggest in my answer.

Comment: @Alien01 — You've edited the question to include code that was given to you in answers. Please show us you *actual* code.

Comment: @dystroy — He isn't … now. It's made the question even more confusing.

Comment: sorry guys for creating confusion....I cannt put actual code as its specific to some problem..but I have to use window load event listener to intialize some object

Comment: it would be gr8 if someone can explain me why I cannt call showHTML from window load event listener

Comment: @Alien01 That's because if you call document.write after document load it opens a new document, thus replacing the old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `test2.js` file is executed, it adds a complete document after which is like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>
<input type='button' name='button'  style='width:100px;height:50px;' onclick='show();' />
</body></html>
```

There isn't any test1.js file anymore, the `test1.js` inclusion is out of your HTML document.

What you could do, if you really want to generate the whole html in your script, is start with a valid HTML file inluding the js script in its header and then changing only the body, for example like this

```
function showHTML() {
    var html = "<input type='button' name='button'  style='width:100px;height:50px;' onclick='show();' />";
    document.body.innerHTML = html;
}
document.onload = showHTML();
```

But the usual practice is only add or change elements, not replacing the whole body with an HTML string.

---

**EDIT :** in my tests, both in FF and Chrome, the browser somewhat keeps the function defined in `test1.js` even while the document started after, and the whole works. So I vote to close as not a real question too.

---

**EDIT 2, to make clear the real problem :**

In fact OP called the showHTML function from a `onload` event handler. So the `document.write` was called after document load, which [results in the replacing of the document by a new one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write).

Never call `document.write` apart during initial execution.

Comment: It does not rewrite the entire document. Since `document.write` is being called inline, it will be called while the document is still in an open state, and will just append to the portion of the document that has been parsed so far.